# <H2> followed by <Sup>

Tags: html, css, tags

Well, I have a H2 tag with a company name and next to that in the same line we need to have a Superscript tag (TM), I have:

```
<h1 class="Red">Company Name</h1><sup>&#8482;</sup>
```

I get:

**Company Name**

™

I guess there is a way to avoid this newline between those tags using CSS or something but I am not able to figure it out, I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper format is to wrap the entire phrase inside your `<h1>` tag like so

`<h1 class="Red">Company Name<sup>&#8482;</sup></h1>`

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind with this answer that any styles you apply to the h1 tag will apply to your sup tag as well.

```
<h1 class="Red">Company Name<sup>&#8482;</sup></h1>
```

The main issue I run into with sup tags is that they can push up the line-height on lines containing them. 
It's easy to fix with the following CSS; just figured it was worth mentioning.

```
h1.Red sup { line-height: .1em;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS.

```
.Red {
    display:inline;
}
```

Header tags default to line breaks so you need to set it to display inline which will not break after the end h tag

Comment: I tried but the problem was that It was a centred heading and it just messed up everything, above answer work fine. Thanks anyway.